# Swift Как автоматически менять размер Title в NavigationBar?

Tags: swift, текст, resize, navigationbar

Подскажите плиз, как менять автоматически размер шрифта?
Например текст не помещается (слева еще одна клавиша должна быть - на рисунке не отображена)
[image: Не отображается полностью]

А в другой ситуации, когда символов меньше - отображается
[image: Отображается полностью]

Я могу руками уменьшить размер шрифта с 20 на 15, но это как то не удобно делать каждый раз. Проблема возникает на маленьких экранах Iphone 4/5, на других устройствах проблем нет.

```
self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "FrizQuadrataC", size: 15)!,NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Существуют ли какие то иные варианты решения этого вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете установить как `title` `UILabel`, которой зададите возможность изменения размера текста:

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.text = "Your title"
titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17) // Нужный шрифт
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.75 // Минимальный относительный размер шрифта 
navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```